# How to train Naive Bayes Classifier for n-gram (movie_reviews)

Tags: python, nlp, classification, nltk

Below is the code of training `Naive Bayes Classifier` on `movie_reviews` dataset for `unigram` model. I want to train and analyze its performance by considering `bigram`, `trigram` model. How can we do it.

```
import nltk.classify.util
from nltk.classify import NaiveBayesClassifier
from nltk.corpus import movie_reviews
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize

def create_word_features(words):
    useful_words = [word for word in words if word not in stopwords.words("english")] 
    my_dict = dict([(word, True) for word in useful_words])
    return my_dict

pos_data = []
for fileid in movie_reviews.fileids('pos'):
    words = movie_reviews.words(fileid)
    pos_data.append((create_word_features(words), "positive"))    

neg_data = []
for fileid in movie_reviews.fileids('neg'):
    words = movie_reviews.words(fileid)
    neg_data.append((create_word_features(words), "negative")) 

train_set = pos_data[:800] + neg_data[:800]
test_set =  pos_data[800:] + neg_data[800:]

classifier = NaiveBayesClassifier.train(train_set)

accuracy = nltk.classify.util.accuracy(classifier, test_set)
```

Comment: Did you see the post : [n-grams with Naive Bayes classifier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14003291/n-grams-with-naive-bayes-classifier) ?

Comment: or : [n-grams with Naive Bayes classifier Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19209895/n-grams-with-naive-bayes-classifier-error)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Simply change your featurizer

```
from nltk import ngrams

def create_ngram_features(words, n=2):
    ngram_vocab = ngrams(words, n)
    my_dict = dict([(ng, True) for ng in ngram_vocab])
    return my_dict
```

---

BTW, your code will be a lot faster if you change your featurizer to do use a set for your stopword list and initialize it only once.

```
stoplist = set(stopwords.words("english"))

def create_word_features(words):
    useful_words = [word for word in words if word not in stoplist] 
    my_dict = dict([(word, True) for word in useful_words])
    return my_dict
```

Someone should really tell the NLTK people to convert the stopwords list into a set type since it's "technically" a unique list (i.e. a set).

```
>>> from nltk.corpus import stopwords
>>> type(stopwords.words('english'))
<class 'list'>
>>> type(set(stopwords.words('english')))
<class 'set'>
```

---

## For the fun of benchmarking

```
import nltk.classify.util
from nltk.classify import NaiveBayesClassifier
from nltk.corpus import movie_reviews
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize
from nltk import ngrams

def create_ngram_features(words, n=2):
    ngram_vocab = ngrams(words, n)
    my_dict = dict([(ng, True) for ng in ngram_vocab])
    return my_dict

for n in [1,2,3,4,5]:
    pos_data = []
    for fileid in movie_reviews.fileids('pos'):
        words = movie_reviews.words(fileid)
        pos_data.append((create_ngram_features(words, n), "positive"))    

    neg_data = []
    for fileid in movie_reviews.fileids('neg'):
        words = movie_reviews.words(fileid)
        neg_data.append((create_ngram_features(words, n), "negative")) 

    train_set = pos_data[:800] + neg_data[:800]
    test_set =  pos_data[800:] + neg_data[800:]

    classifier = NaiveBayesClassifier.train(train_set)

    accuracy = nltk.classify.util.accuracy(classifier, test_set)
    print(str(n)+'-gram accuracy:', accuracy)
```

[out]:

```
1-gram accuracy: 0.735
2-gram accuracy: 0.7625
3-gram accuracy: 0.8275
4-gram accuracy: 0.8125
5-gram accuracy: 0.74
```

Your original code returns an accuracy of 0.725.

## Use more orders of ngrams

```
import nltk.classify.util
from nltk.classify import NaiveBayesClassifier
from nltk.corpus import movie_reviews
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize
from nltk import everygrams

def create_ngram_features(words, n=2):
    ngram_vocab = everygrams(words, 1, n)
    my_dict = dict([(ng, True) for ng in ngram_vocab])
    return my_dict

for n in range(1,6):
    pos_data = []
    for fileid in movie_reviews.fileids('pos'):
        words = movie_reviews.words(fileid)
        pos_data.append((create_ngram_features(words, n), "positive"))    

    neg_data = []
    for fileid in movie_reviews.fileids('neg'):
        words = movie_reviews.words(fileid)
        neg_data.append((create_ngram_features(words, n), "negative")) 

    train_set = pos_data[:800] + neg_data[:800]
    test_set =  pos_data[800:] + neg_data[800:]
    classifier = NaiveBayesClassifier.train(train_set)

    accuracy = nltk.classify.util.accuracy(classifier, test_set)
    print('1-gram to', str(n)+'-gram accuracy:', accuracy)
```

[out]:

```
1-gram to 1-gram accuracy: 0.735
1-gram to 2-gram accuracy: 0.7625
1-gram to 3-gram accuracy: 0.7875
1-gram to 4-gram accuracy: 0.8
1-gram to 5-gram accuracy: 0.82
```

Comment: I don't think there will be any use of set() function here `stoplist = set(stopwords.words("english"))` as `stopwords.words("english")` is already  a set.

Comment: `stopwords.words("english")` technically a "set" because it's a unique list but the native python type is a list. Casting it into a set and initializing it only once do speed up the code =)

Comment: Ohh Thanks I get it

Answer (score 0):

There is a shorter way for this. You can use `CountVectorizer` method of sklearn library with a n-gram range parameter:

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
import numpy as np
corpus = [
    'This is the first document.',
    'This document is the second document.',
    'And this is the third one.',
    'Is this the first document?',
]
model = CountVectorizer(ngram_range = (2, 2), stop_words='english')
matrix = model.fit_transform(corpus).toarray()
df_output = pd.DataFrame(data = matrix, columns = model.get_feature_names())
df_output.T.tail(5)
```

Result will be:

```
                0   1   2   3
document second 0   1   0   0
second document 0   1   0   0
```

For [more](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.CountVectorizer.html).